# MPAndroidChart doesn't show properly

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm implementing `MPAndroidChart` in an android app, but it's showed as in the image:

[image]

basically I'm copying the chart code from the [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335).

I'm doing this in my code:

```
BarChart mChart;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mi_history, container, false);

     mChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));
    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");
    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    mChart.setData(data);

    mChart.setDescription("# of times Alice called Bob");
    return view;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some code may help to find the error.

Comment: Which version are you using? Call `invalidate()` after setting data.

Comment: Im using MPAndroidChart v2.0.9, I already added the invalidate() after the

    mChart.setDescription("# of times Alice called Bob");

but I still get the same